# Why does STS warn me about non matching parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Data Jpa and created a `JpaRepository` for my `User` class.
The repository works but Spring Tool Suite gives me a warning for one method.
Following are examples of my domain model classes and the repository:

**User:**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String username;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( ... )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters & setters

}
```

**Role:**

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // Getters & setters

}
```

**UserRepository:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByRoles(Set<Role> roles);

}
```

STS marks the method `findByRoles()` and gives the following message: `Parameter type (Set<Role>) does not match domain class property definition (Set)`.
Why do I get this warning?

Comment: I think this is a bug or a missing feature in the Spring Data validations in STS. Please file a bug report at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and we will work on a fix for the next release. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the method is wrong. It should be `List<User> findByRolesIn(Set<Role> roles)`, because the argument is a collection.

Answer (score 2):

change your method name like this

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

List<User> findBy_Roles(Set<Role> roles);

}
```

for more details why its complaining see [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) page heading "2.4.3. Property expressions".

Comment: This should not be necessary and in in fact it isn't. I rebuilt my workspace and the warning is gone.

Comment: i have given you a cause and a workaround. if you resolve this by other mean then glad to know that :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now it gives an error with the message `Invalid derived query! No property _Roles found for type User!`.